# Left to right flowing graph in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to create a bokeh line chart to represent cpu usage. I want it to be "live" and update from left to right, like a heartbeat graph - older readings will move to the right until disappearing.

I've created some other plots like a pie chart of disk space and a table connected to a textinput, but I couldn't find info on how to get this specific chart behavior, and I don't know how to proceed.

Any assistance would be much appreciated

Comment: There are examples for doing this using HoloViews at: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Streaming_Data.html

Comment: Thank you! Is this possible through "vanilla" bokeh as well?

Comment: By definition, anything HoloViews does with Bokeh can be done with vanilla Bokeh, if you are willing to reimplement that part of HoloViews yourself.   https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/spectrogram is the best starting point for doing that that I can think of.